# How can I save a set of directions in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

How can I save a set of directions in Google Maps? If I have some directions that I searched for, How can I save these so someone else can use them as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Google's help](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3093455?hl=en), they say simply share/keep the entire URL.  Of course, you could use a url shortening service, but give this a rip to see if it takes you from Golden, CO to Taos Ski Valley, NM:
https://www.google.com/maps/preview#!data=!4m29!3m20!1m1!1sGolden%2C+co!1m1!1sTaos+Ski+Valley%2C+NM!2e0!3m8!1m3!1d122222!2d-97.636522!3d35.5823774!3m2!1i424!2i452!4f13.1!6m2!1m1!1e4!8m2!1e1!2b1!5m2!13m1!1e1!7m4!11m3!1m1!1e1!2b1!6m1!1e1&fid=0i1

Short: http://goo.gl/YMbK8n

Alternately, if you're signed into Google, there should be a "Share" button at the top right corner of the page where you can put a message and add email addresses to share with.

Edit: The "Share" service takes an extraordinarily long time to deliver the email in my tests, just FYI.

Comment: For this to work, you need to click on a particular route (from https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Golden,+Colorado/Taos+Ski+Valley,+New+Mexico/ , for instance), and *then* share. Otherwise the recipient gets a choice of routes.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/) to generate a map with directions then [save it to Google Drive](http://google-latlong.blogspot.com/2014/12/map-this-waygoogle-my-maps-now-in-drive.html) and [share it like a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

Just added:

Once you've got your directions set, click the "Gear" icon at the bottom of the page. Select "Share and embed map".

On the resulting window, you can take the URL as-is, or click the "Short URL" check box to get a shortened URL (obviously), like so: https://goo.gl/maps/NCVIl

Note that it has a "maps" subdirectory, which makes it different from your run-of-the-mill goo.gl-shortened URL.

([source](https://plus.google.com/+GoogleMaps/posts/HeBdPJwNuDz))

Answer (score 1):

If you are on web, on the top right corner next to your pic, you have a "Plus" button, click there and share it with yourself.
This is how I saved a route with custom points I just made...